# How connect non-authority node to the PoA

Tags: proof-of-authority

I have PoA with 2 nodes. And I want add non-authority node from other computer. I followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial) and I can`t connect non-authority node to my PoA.

This is genesis block of my PoA:

```
{
    "name": "DemoPoA",
    "engine": {
        "authorityRound": {
            "params": {
                "gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
                "stepDuration": "5",
                "validators" : {
                    "list": [
                        "0x00Bd138aBD70e2F00903268F3Db08f2D25677C9e",
                        "0x00Aa39d30F0D20FF03a22cCfc30B7EfbFca597C2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x20",
        "minGasLimit": "0x1388",
        "networkID" : "0x2323"
    },
    "genesis": {
        "seal": {
            "authorityRound": {
                "step": "0x0",
                "signature": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
            }
        },
        "difficulty": "0x20000",
        "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
    },
    "nodes": [
        "enode://8e7b7fbd3ea76099f76b52cd8e62ac6c4c85873a80626b9f2919ba5122bc04bacfff937249165a8db46b010b8a06d832ed719fefceb640820e1c08b05472e7b4@136.243.173.186:30300",
        "enode://dd983aa8830b831cf167d6cd8e45263f8a7cf9f269b5b344765ac5ae8a0a4e3125ddec8215039353e08e83e433ca95d0a0523c0d86d998da7eda58e320c7d4a2@136.243.173.186:30301"
    ],
    "accounts": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ecrecover", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "sha256", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "ripemd160", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } } },
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "balance": "1", "builtin": { "name": "identity", "pricing": { "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } } },
        "0x004ec07d2329997267Ec62b4166639513386F32E": { "balance": "10000000000000000000000" }
    }
}
```

And it is my toml file:

```
[parity]
chain = "c:\\Ethereum\\demo-spec.json"
base_path = "c:\\Ethereum\\non-authority"
[network]
reserved_peers = "c:\\Ethereum\\peersNode.txt"
port = 30302
[rpc]
port = 8540
apis = ["web3", "eth", "net", "personal", "parity", "parity_set", "traces", "rpc", "parity_accounts"]
interface = "185.168.130.59"
```

peersNode.txt contains:

```
enode://8e7b7fbd3ea76099f76b52cd8e62ac6c4c85873a80626b9f2919ba5122bc04bacfff937249165a8db46b010b8a06d832ed719fefceb640820e1c08b05472e7b4@136.243.173.186:30300
enode://dd983aa8830b831cf167d6cd8e45263f8a7cf9f269b5b344765ac5ae8a0a4e3125ddec8215039353e08e83e433ca95d0a0523c0d86d998da7eda58e320c7d4a2@136.243.173.186:30301
```

Wgen I trying add new non-authority node I create new PoA - chain instead of add non-authority node to my PoA.
What am I doing wrong?